# Bounding the integral of the tails of a random variable.

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, inequality, expectation

I found an argument like this in a book, but I couldn't understand how we got this bound.

Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables. For some $\delta > 0$ and all
$n \geq 1$,
$$
\int_{|X_n| \geq M} |X_n| \, dP \leq \frac{1}{M^\delta} E[|X_n|^{1 + \delta}].
$$

How can I justify this bound?

Comment: This is part of the argument used to show that if $\{X_n\}$ converges to $X$ in distribution and if for some $\delta >0$ and all$n \geq 1$ we have $E[|X_n|^{1 + \delta}] \leq \infty$, then $\{ X_n \}$ is uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We don't need a sequence, only the fact that if $X$ is a non-negative random variable, then 
   $$\int_{\{X\geqslant M\}}X\mathrm d\mathbb P\leqslant \frac 1{M^\delta}\mathbb E[X^{1+\delta}].$$
2. To see that, notice that $$X\cdot\chi_{\{X\geqslant M\}}\leqslant \frac{X^{1+\delta}}{M^\delta},$$
   then integrate.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the quick reply! I'm not sure I understand where $X\cdot\chi_{\{X\geqslant M\}}\leqslant \frac{X^{1+\delta}}{M^\delta}$ comes from. To be clear, what does the $\chi$ mean?

Comment: Oh, I see. $\chi$ is the indicator function and so if $M$ is the smallest value that $X$ takes, then $\left ( \frac{X}{M} \right ) \geq 1$, so $\left ( \frac{X}{M} \right )^\delta \geq 1$.